# run-time errors - pointers in c

Tags: c, function, pointers

I wrote a program which prints all the letters in English but there is a run - time error in the code which I wrote.  Where is it?  Why did it happened? 
Can you please help me and solve it?

```
void printArray(char* p, int len)
{
    for( p ; p < p + len ; p++ )
    {
        printf("%c", *p);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
    char* abc = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    printArray(abc, 26);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How can you tell there is a run-time error?

Comment: because i tried to run that and there was a run time error

Comment: Did you get a message? Did your computer lock up? What occurred that told you there was an error?

Comment: " Where is it?" - That's what you are supposed to tell. We then can tell you why it occured. Learn using a debugger.

Comment: There are three answers that suggest an infinite loop, but you say there is a runtime error report.  The three answers must all be wrong - I'll downvote them all.

Comment: Note `for(p;` is the same as `for(;`

Answer (score 4):

When will `p` not be less that `p + len`?

```
for( p ; p < p + len ; p++ ) // Loop forever
```

You might want something like:

```
char* stop = p + len;
for( p ; p < stop ; p++ )
```

Answer (score 1):

`p < p + len` is never false --> infinite loop.

Suggest

```
for(int i = 0; i<len ; i++ )
{
    printf("%c", p[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are editing p as you check against it "p < p + len" this loop will never end. p will always be less than itself plus a constant.
try it like

```
char* end = p + len;
for(p ; p < end; p++)
```

then it should work